# Please identify the set(s) that these come from

Tags: set-identification

I have bought an auction lot of LEGO packs. I thought that I'd be able to identify the instructions from the QR codes on the bags, but apparently not. Is anyone here able to help?

[image: img3]

[image: img2]

[image: img1]

[image: img4]

<sup>Slightly better photos:
(http://www.imagebam.com/image/f8759e1346605880)

(http://www.imagebam.com/image/9b92721346606001)

(http://www.imagebam.com/image/6a46d51346606118)

(http://www.imagebam.com/image/89c6771346606190)</sup>

Comment: I had to shrink the image quality in order to upload the images, I hope that's fine with you. I'm still keeping the older links since they hold the original photos, which weren't modified.

Comment: Items in the last photo hardly can be used to identify the set since they are stored in ziploc bags rather than sealed polybag. Which means there could a random mix of bricks.

Comment: @Alex Looks like some random mix indeed. That blue tile is part of only [12 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30258pb018&in=S). I can't see any match. And I think mindstormsboi has already checked with the grille pieces...

Comment: @Uli Yeah, I don't really understand why you'd put a computer screen into  a building that's colored like a cave/mountain, and neither do I understand why you'd put those grilles in such build either. There are several other unique parts in the bag that don't really match the theme as well. Perhaps you can add this info to your existing answer.

Comment: @mindstormsboi I wonder if those extra parts were being advertisedv as such in the auction. That would really explain their randomness...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ho Ho Ho!

Your four sealed bags (from first through third images) are **Mr. Claus and Mrs. Claus**

- Item No: [40274-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=40274-1#T=I)

[image]

[Building instructions](https://www.lego.com/en-my/service/buildinginstructions/search?q=40274) at lego.com

Comment: It seems like the polybags on 3rd photo are from the same set as well.

Comment: @Alex I think you're right. The building instructions show two bags (#1 for her, #2 for him). But I can see 4 bags in an unboxing video on youtube. Looks like the smaller parts are in 2 seperate bags.

Comment: Thanks guys. That's something to go on at least. And a festive ornament for my lads room for a few years it would seem!  